# How to Microbenchmark using data from a file?

Tags: scala, performance, microbenchmark, scalameter

I'm trying to microbenchmark two different implementations of calculating a running median using [Scalameter](http://scalameter.github.io/home/gettingstarted/0.7/index.html). I've some test files, small and large, from where the numbers are going to come from. Problem is, the following code completes instantly without generating any sort of benchmark at all.

```
object MedianMaintenanceBenchmark extends Bench[Double] {

  /* configuration */

  lazy val executor = LocalExecutor(
    new Warmer.Default,
    Aggregator.median[Double],
    measurer
  )
  lazy val measurer = new Measurer.Default
  lazy val reporter = new LoggingReporter[Double]
  lazy val persistor: Persistor.None.type = Persistor.None

  /* inputs */

  private val files: Gen[String] = Gen.enumeration("files")("median-test")
  private val num: Gen[Seq[Int]] = (for (f <- files) yield numbers(f)).cached

  /* tests */

  performance of "MedianMaintenance" config (
    exec.benchRuns -> 10
    ) in {
    measure method "using heap" in {
      using(num) in {
        xs => MedianMaintenanceUsingHeaps(xs).medians
      }
    }
  }

  private def numbers(filename: String): Seq[Int] = // elided
}
```

**Output:**

```
::Benchmark MedianMaintenance.using heap::
cores: 8
hostname: ***
name: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
osArch: x86_64
osName: Mac OS X
vendor: Azul Systems, Inc.
version: 11.0.1+13-LTS
Parameters(files -> median-test): 3.612799 ms
```

What is going on here?

**Edit:**

Changing the code as follows atleast does something, but doesn't honor the options. It seems to be running the test a total of 18 times for file 'Median', which is not a sum of 3 + 10.

```
object MedianMaintenanceBenchmark extends Bench.ForkedTime {

  /* configuration */
  override def aggregator: Aggregator[Double] = Aggregator.median

  private val opts = Context(
    exec.minWarmupRuns-> 3,
    exec.maxWarmupRuns -> 3,
    exec.benchRuns -> 10,
    exec.jvmflags -> List("-Xms2g", "-Xmx2g")
  )

  /* inputs */

  private val files: Gen[String] = Gen.enumeration("files")("median-test", "Median")
  private val num: Gen[Seq[Int]] = (for (f <- files) yield numbers(f)).cached

  /* tests */

  performance of "MedianMaintenance" config opts in {
    measure method "using heap" in {
      using(num) in {
        xs => MedianMaintenanceUsingHeaps(xs).medians
      }
    }

    measure method "using red-black BST" in {
      using(num) in {
        xs => MedianMaintenanceUsingRedBlackTree(xs).medians
      }
    }
  }

  private def numbers(filename: String): Seq[Int] = // elided
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP here: after several hours, I was finally able to get through the pathetically outdated documentation, what exists anyway, and figure out the following:

In addition to my edit above, there are several ways to override execution count et. al.

1. For all benchmarks in the current file, use `override def defaultConfig: Context = Context(exec.benchRuns -> 10)`
2. For a specific benchmark, define inline or define a `val opts: Context` and use  `config opts in` DSL.
3. For a specific method, do same as #2 except use `config opts in` at method DSL.
4. The docs claim that it's possible to override configurations for each "curve", but I was not able to find what a "curve" is or how to override configurations for it.

independentSamples = number of independent JVMs spawned.

Warmup is run `(minWarmupRuns to maxWarmupRuns)` times on each JVM (makes sense) using one set of test data (picked randomly?), then the tests are run on each JVM for `benchRuns` times.
How many warmups are run depends on the detection of "steady state". There seems to be one execution unaccounted for in the end for each JVM.

```
Total number of executions = independentSamples * ((minWarmupRuns to maxWarmupRuns) + benchRuns + 1)
```

For instance, given:

```
Context(
  exec.minWarmupRuns -> 5,
  exec.maxWarmupRuns -> 5,
  exec.benchRuns -> 10,
  exec.independentSamples -> 2
)
```

There will be 32 executions of the code under test.